Pursuing PhD 5 years after master's
I live in Germany and want to continue my studies in Pharmaceutical engineering with a PhD. Since it has been 5 years since my master's degree, do I have any chance to be accepted and what can I do for this purpose?

It absolutely is possible. I have a friend who did her MSc in Portugal, worked for a few years in a pharmacy, then went for a PhD in Czechia, fully paid. Email professors that had interesting classes or research. Certainly they can recommend programs or colleagues.

Do you wish to study in Germany or are you looking more broadly?

I had a 5 years gap between my master's and Ph.D., both in fluid mechanics. But I studied all those 5 years myself for my future Ph.D. I was solving problems, I was thinking about research ideas.

@Buffy does this changes for united states?

You would be considered in the US.

@Buffy Yes, I did my masters in 2020. Can you please let me know how it is thought in USA?

You would be considered like anyone else but note that letters of recommendation are especially important here. See the answer for the US here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368

Generally speaking, the answer is: yes, you may be accepted.
There is no reason why industrial experience should spoil your chances.
Moreover, to a potential advisor whose research is related to industry, you and your experience may become a useful acquisition.
Explore the web pages of the departments to which you wish to apply. Find professors whose research scope correlates with your work experience (and, ideally, with the topic of your Master's thesis).  Don't hesitate to write to them directly.  There would be nothing unusual in doing so.  A sample of such a letter, and some related discussion is offered here.
Good luck with your applications!


do I have any chance to be accepted and what can I do for this purpose?

I'm not German, but presumably if you have the aptitude needed to get into a PHD program (where academic research and so on are stressed heavily) of this kind, then yes.

May I point out that, with few exceptions, there are no 'PhD programs' in Germany.

Congratulations on deciding to complete a PhD in pharmaceutical engineering. Speaking from the perspective of a current graduate student, I'm sure that this will represent an amazing portion of your life!
It is absolutely possible to pursue a PhD five years after your Masters degree. In fact, you may be at somewhat of an advantage, given that during those five years, your academic horizons were no doubt expanded, and you may have gained industry experience.
That being said, there will be a couple of challenges given the fact that you are currently not in education, so may not being receiving academic support during your application. If this is the case, I could offer a couple of suggestions:

Reach out to the lecturers or other staff from your Masters. Your past lecturers will no doubt want to help you, whether that be with some advice, suggestions of contacts, or letters of recommendations.
Reflect on and refine your research interests. After a five-year gap, it's useful to reflect on your current interests in the field, especially since your passions or areas of focus may have changed during the time away from education. Having a clear and focused research interest is important for a strong PhD proposal. Perhaps it would be useful to read through some academic journals in order to understand any evolution in the field since your Masters.
Leverage your professional experience. Sit down and relfect on all the professional experience you have had in the time out of education, because PhD programs will value candidates with practical insights. Write down all of the skills that you aquired so that you have something to talk about in your application and interview.
Brush up on your academic skills. Science gets rusty after a while, and so it may benefit you to brush up on some learning. Perhaps there are some texbtooks laying around which you could flick through, some problems to work through online, or even a lectuer series on YouTube. It's worth brushing up on now, as in the interview section of a PhD application, you may be asked specific questions concerning your field of study.
Reach out to potential supervisors. Identify potential supervisors at unviersities whose corresponding department aligns with your interests. Write an email expressing your interest in the potential of carrying out a PhD there. You could even ask for their advice. They may remember your name when they are looking through the applications, and they will remember that you were proactive.


This seems like it might have been at least partially AI generated. If this is the case, please note that we have a policy prohibiting AI-generated content on this stack.

@cag51 Thank you for the comment, it's good to see that people are monitoring the site to stop potential AI generated answer. This response is actually not generated by AI (I think one can tell as there are a few spelling mistakes dotted around it)- it is based on my own experiences, and having met people who have been out of education for some time. I do try to lay-out my responses in a clean manner, although if that makes it seem AI generated, I will try to add more personality to them. I do like laying it out with bullet points, however, as I find it much easier to read.
